# Python does not properly process text input from an HTML textarea

Tags: python, html, forms, textarea, pyramid

I have a standard form on an HTML page with the usual input types: `text`, `select`, `submit`. Using Python (the [Pyramid](http://pylonsproject.org/) framework) to process these forms has been straightforward and without issue.

In this particular form, though, I have needed to use a `textarea` to accept longer, multi-line input.  When processing the user input in Python, I've used the following code:

```
try:
    some_input = request.params['form_element'].decode('utf-8')
except:
    some_input = None
```

This works for `text` input, but does not for `textarea` input.  `textarea` input is not processed when a unicode character is included, and throws the following error:

```
(<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>, UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u'some text then a unicode character \u2013 and some more text', 14, 15, 'ordinal not in range(128)'), <traceback object at 0x10265ca70>)
```

Is there any reason for this? It looks like it's assuming that the `textarea` input is being treated as ASCII instead of UTF-8, but I'm not sure how to change this.

More information: the page from which the form is being submitted is an HTML5 page with the charset set to UTF-8.

**EDIT:** [Wladimir Palant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785541/wladimir-palant) suggested  that it's already been decoded and I check this:

`print isinstance(request.params['form_element'], str)` returns `False`

`print isinstance(request.params['form_element'], unicode)` returns `True`

Comment: Should we know which framework you are using?

Comment: It's [Pyramid](http://pylonsproject.org/).  I'll clarify it in the question.

Comment: Sounds like your parameter has been decoded already and you are trying to use `.decode("utf-8")` on Unicode data. Want to check `isinstance(request.params['form_element'], str)` and `isinstance(request.params['form_element'], unicode)`?

Comment: You're right, Wladimir.  If you want to put it as the answer I'll accept it.  It turns out that I was using `decode` when I needed to use `encode`.  Additionally, I tested my other form inputs and found that they too failed when using utf-8 characters instead of just ASCII characters (I thought I'd tested it earlier and it worked, but apparently I hadn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between a input[type=text] and a textarea when the data is submitted. The problem you describe should happen in both.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but WebOb, which is used in Pyramid, does the decoding for you. You get Unicode already, so there is no need to decode or encode anything. Also, you can use unicode for the response, and it will be encoded automatically. You rarely have to use encode or decode in Pyramid applications.